# Receive different result from 2 empty form inputs

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

In a `.jsp` page I have a form (`POST` method):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="text"  list="materials" class="form-control" name="material"/>
     <datalist id="materials"></datalist>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" >
    </div>
</div>
```

I delete the html5 element `required` from the input to see what happens if the user submit the form without filling these inputs. In my servlet, I get this:

```
String material = request.getParameter("material");
String quantity = request.getParameter("quantity");
System.out.println("material="+ material + "-quantity=" + quantity);
```

and I get:

> material=-quantity=null

The fact that I receive an empty string and a `null` result is it because of the diferrent `type` in the input?

Comment: Can you please post your whole code, the HTML form and the servlet code?

Comment: @chsdk I added the exact code from the html form, the serlvet code is the above.. It's too big to paste it here..

Comment: Are you using `method="POST"` in the form?

Comment: yes, `post` method

Comment: Ok, and is this server code in the `doPost` method?

Comment: It is in the `protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` where `@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }`

Comment: That's how it should be, I just wanted to make sure, it's in the right place.